# exotic font size calculation using css3 calc

Tags: css

I would like to dynamically change font size between width 1300px and 1880px.

However, the space that I have available only changes in 1 dimension.

```
1300px:

|--|------------------------|--|
   | container: 1170px      |

1880px:

|------|------------------------|------|
       | container: 1170px      |
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the width of the container doesn't change, but the height of the element does, because I use:

```
.inner
  height: calc(0.2 * 100vw)
```

Tried using:

```
font-size: 2.5vw
```

But my fonts grow in two dimensions that way, so eventually what fits inside the inner div on larger screen sizes it doesn't.

Right now I'm using:

```
<style>
    .outer {
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }
    .inner{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: calc(.2 * 100vw);
        background: white;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 42px;
        max-width: 66%;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1879px){
        h2{
            font-size: 2.5vw;
            /*shameful fix: at 1300px the 34px font is ok, also at 1880px the 44px is ok*/
            font-size: calc(34px + ((100vw - 1300px)/58));
            line-height: calc(42px + ((100vw - 1300px)/58));
        }
    }
    </style>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>
            Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum
            Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum
            Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum Lots of lorem ipsum
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this custom calculation it works, but with 2.5vw it wont.
And also looked up, you can't use square root in css calc.

**Edit:** I found some more interesting stuff regarding fonts that change sizes on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/).

Comment: Can it be done with a simpler calc, instead of this ugly long one?

Comment: Like I mentioned the problem is that fonts grow both in height and width, but the container only grows in height.

Comment: My soul is a little calmer now that I found this on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/):
`font-size: calc( 14px + 8 * ((100vw - 500px) / 1500));`

Comment: When I first asked this question I was actually thinking of Is there a better formula to do what I intended to do, and not _simplify what I came up with (and does the job - sorta, but it's ugly)_. And simplification may not be the best idea because then if someone else looks at it they'll have no clue whatsoever, why is that calc the way it is.
If left in it's original form, they may not have no clue either, but there is at least a chance that they'll understand.